# Comprobar si existen usuarios en la BD

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy comprobando si existen usuarios en mi BD atraves de un formulario para introducir el correo electrónico y la contraseña. Compruebo en un archivo PHP si el correo y la contraseña existen en la base de datos, pero me tira error **Undefined index: password** y no se porque.

**Código html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Introduce tu usuario</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introduce tu usuario:</h1>
        <form method="get" action="comprobar.php">
            <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
            <input type="text" name="correo"><br/><br/>
            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código php:**

```
<?php
    $correo=$_GET["correo"];
    $password=$_GET["password"];

    //Conexion con el servidor de base de datos
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdusuarios");

    //Escribimos la consulta que queremos hacer
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    //Ejecutamos la consulta
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    $swcorreo=0;
    $swpassword=0;

    //Vamos leyendo cada fila y comprobando los campos
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {
        if(strcmp($fila["correo"], $correo) === 0)
        {
            $swcorreo=1;
        }
        if(strcmp($fila["password"], $password) === 0)
        {
            $swpassword=1;
        }
    }

    //Mostramos si existe el usuario
    if($swcorreo==1 && $swpassword==1)
    {
        echo "<h1>La cuenta existe</h1>";
    }else
    {
        echo "<h1>La cuenta no existe</h1>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como el select dice "*" en lugar de listar los campos que necesitas y no incluiste el número de linea donde se presenta el error estoy adivinando:

Fijate si en la base de datos el nombre del campo es realmente "password" lo que afecta a $fila["password"] en el programa.

Comment: Efectivamente el campo en la BD se llama contraseña y no password, de todos modos me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Es como si no enviara la contraseña a través del formulario

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta (password x contraseña) y por favor agregá cual es la linea que da el error. Si pudieras evitar la ñ en el nombre del campo podriamos descartar eso tambien.

Comment: Ese es el error, no admite la ñ, asique le he cambiado el nombre por password en vez de contraseña y funciona. Gracias amigo